# How do I find the source line of a crashing DLL giving the DLL's name and the address of the fault?

Tags: windbg, pdb-files

The official way to do this appears to be to use WinDbg.  That should be able to give me the information I need, very easily.  However, I don't have WinDbg, and my attempts to install it have failed for no known reason.  So, is there another way to find my bad line of code?  Or, is there a way other than using Microsoft's Windows SDK installer to get WinDbg?

My DLL is an unmanaged DLL (no CLR) built using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: i am not convinced windbg installation fails i have umpteen windbg versions side by side including insider previews   so be it do you have any debugger that runs in your machine ollydbg ?  idadbg ? vs dbg?  your own contraption ??  set it  as post mortem debugger and let it attach on crash and plow from there (without windbg and its ability to use pdb files tracing back to src line is tedious but possible)

Comment: Maybe the installation of Windbg does not fail - it just does not have a UI. If you didn't get an error message, it's likely installed. Besides the DLL you will need PDB files.

Comment: Code Machine provides some direct downloads of the WinDbg MSIs: http://codemachine.com/downloads.html - and you don't neccessarily need WinDbg. You can also use Visual Studio to analyze crash dump files.

Comment: Do you have the pdb (symbol) file? the connection to the source line is stored in the pdb and not in the dll itself.